# Repeat drop down validation entry based on matches in second column in excel / VBA

Tags: excel, vba, validation

I have a column with drop-down options (A), and one with a list of values (B).

```
A B
M 1
L 2
H 3
  1
  1
  3
```

If I select from the drop-down in A, is there a simple solution in VBA to repeat that value in A for every matching instance in B?

So desired output:

```
A B
M 1
L 2
H 3
M 1
M 1
H 3
```

Appreciate any solutions!

Comment: You can see in Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range) if the value of cells in column A changes, then set the value of cells below it as desired.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this:

```
Sub match()

Dim lrA, lrB, i, j As Long

lrA = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
lrB = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 2 To lrB
    If IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) Then
        For j = 2 To lrA
            If Cells(i, 2).Value = Cells(j, 2) Then Cells(i, 1).Value = Cells(j, 1).Value
        Next j
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: When you do `Dim lrA, lrB, i, j As Long` you are declaring lrA, lrB and i as variants. You should use `Dim lrA As Long, lrB As Long, i As Long, j As Long` to be more explicit.

Comment: You're right, but without option Explicit, function calling and a macro of this size I didn't even have to declare them, right?

Comment: Correct. It’s not optimal or a good practice, but you’ll still be okay

Answer (score 0):

you could use:

```
Sub RepeatValuesInA()
    Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=INDEX(R1C:R[-1]C,MATCH(RC[1],R1C2:R[-1]C2,0))"
End Sub
```

or, if you want to get rid of formulas:

```
Sub RepeatValuesInA()
   With Range("B1", Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp)).Offset(, -1)
       .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Formula = "=INDEX(R1C:R[-1]C,MATCH(RC[1],R1C2:R[-1]C2,0))"
       .Value = .Value
   End With
End Sub
```